# Client-Server communication- Looking for best solution

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, wcf, service

I have an application in WPF c# which will run on client machine. Another application (maybe some kind of service) on a particular server will be running all the time and will wait for any incoming message from the client app. As soon as the server receives a request from any of the client application, it triggers a command line process and also responds to the client about the staring info(whether it was successful or not) and as well as when the command line process is finished it again responds to the calling client application that it got finished.

I am new to in this area. 
So my question is should I use normal windows service or Web service or WCF?(Some kind of link to a demo project will really help). Any other suggestion are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if your clients will be outside of your firewall or with in the same intranet. We have intranet scenario, and we use WCF service that communicates with WPF based applications over the internal network. WCF provides Duplex feature which enables two-way client server communication using an easy to implement programming model. I recently wrote an [article](https://thesaadworld.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/wcf-duplex-services/) on this and it can give you a head start for the WCF way. 
However, WCF does not have the best support for callbacks over the internet and you may have to look in to effectively using it in your case. But if it is intranet, then my suggestion is surely to go for the WCF way. Hope it helps.